# Meaning of the verb "dog" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

It was in the 5th episode of the 5th season of *The Office*.

> Here is the context: Pete: That’s perfect. You know what would be even
> more hilarious? Remember that thing we did when Jim was in high school
> with his girlfriend? Tom: Right! That would be hilarious! We should
> totally **dog** her, about being an artist, never making any money!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to pester or tease her.
[Merriam-Webster "dog"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dog)

> transitive verb:
> c: to bother or pester persistently
> *dogged him about his grades*

Comment: There's another meaning which is more about insulting or abusing someone, in the sense of "treating someone like a dog". You'll sometimes hear *dogging [someone] out*. I think this example is meant more in that sense - it's not about generally bothering someone, it's about dragging them to make them feel bad.